# The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Uri'

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http, dart-http

I have a project whereby I am using the http package to make various http requests. I recently updated the package and I cannot append url links to the end of the base url that I have. Here is the sample code

```
  var _url = Uri.parse('url here');

  var token;

  _getToken() async {
    SharedPreferences localStorage = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    token = jsonDecode(localStorage.getString('token'))['token'];
  }

  authData(data, apiUrl) async {
    try {
      var fullUrl = _url +  apiUrl;
      return await http.post(fullUrl,
          body: jsonEncode(data), headers: _setHeaders());
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

This is the error it displays

```
The operator '+' isn't defined for the type 'Uri'.
Try defining the operator '+'.dartundefined_operator
```

The error occurs at `var fullUrl = _url +  apiUrl;` specifically the + operator. Before updating it worked well however I cannot find the solution to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use it this way, by combining your strings first, then parsing your Uri. Uri class\object is not a string that you can concatenate strings by using +. Do the following:

```
String _urlBase = 'http://192.168.1.236/connect/api/v1';
```

keep the getToken() function as it as, and then use this:

```
authData(data, apiUrl) async {
try {
  String _finalUrl = _urlBase + apiUrl;
  Uri _uri = Uri.parse(_finalUrl);
  return await http.post(_uri,
      body: jsonEncode(data), headers: _setHeaders());
} catch (e) {
  print(e);
}
}
```

That should solve your problem.